# Parse xml elements with no root element using Linq in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

I have the following xml package that I can't seem to query since it doesn't contain a root element. Unfortunately, the xml payload can't be changed, so I'm stuck w/ this approach. I'm wondering if there's good way to do this with changes to my example. I tried using DesendantsAndSelf as well, but couldn't make it work. Tnx for your help.

```
    string xml = @"<book number='3'>
                    <description>Test</description>
                    <chapter number='3-1-1'>
                        <description>Test</description>
                    </chapter>
                    <chapter number='3-1-2'>
                        <description>Test</description>
                    </chapter>
                    </book>";
```

Here's my code example:

```
                    XElement element= XElement.Parse(xml);
                    List<Book> books = ( from t in element.Descendants("book")
                        select new Book
                        {
                            number = (String)t.Attribute("number"),
                            description = (String)t.Element("description").Value,

                            // Load the chapter information
                            chapters = t.Elements("chapter")
                                .Select(te => new Chapter
                            {
                                number = (String)te.Attribute("number"),
                                description = (String)t.Element("description").Value
                            }).ToList(),                                    
                        }).ToList();

            foreach(var d in books)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("number = {0}: description = {1}",d.number,d.description));
                foreach(var c in d.chapters)
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("number = {0}: description = {1}",c.number,c.description));
            }
```

This is my class object:

```
public class Book
{
    public String number { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
    public List<Chapter> chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public String number { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `book` is your root element. If you have multiple `book` elements in one string just wrap it in a dummy element (e.g. `"<root>" + xml + "</root>"`;

Comment: That's good idea. But if book is the root element why won't the Linq query work correctly. Since it not finding the book elements. Is using element.Descendants("book") not correct?

Comment: No because `element` in this case _is_ the `book` element. It has no decendants of type `book`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `XElement element= XElement.Parse(xml);` to `var element = XDocument.Parse(xml);`. In this case you will get a `XDocument` instance, which has a `book` descendant. If you use `XElement element= XElement.Parse(xml);` you current element would be `book` which doesn't have any `book` descendants.